# How to get value of element via attribute in Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing

I am new to Linq so apologies for very basic question.

i have following kind of XML

```
<QuestionSet type="MCQ">
  <Question>

    What will the output of following

       // main()
       // {
        // int x = 10, y = 15;
        // x = x++;
        // y = ++y;
        // printf("%d, %d", x, y);
       // }
    </Question>"

<Options>
    <Option number="1">10, 15</Option>
    <Option number="2">10, 16</Option>
    <Option number="3">11, 15</Option>
    <Option number="4">11, 16</Option>
  </Options>
</QuestionSet>
```

I want to get the option values by attributes say 1, 2 , 3 and four.

Comment: I tried as follows....                      mcqTest = XElement.Load(SRI.Stream);
            var questionSet = from item in mcqTest.Elements("QuestionSet") select item;

            foreach (XElement eachQuestion in questionSet)
            {

                IEnumerable<XElement> rows = from row in questionSet.Descendants("Options")
                                             where (string)row.Attribute("number") == "2"
                                             select row;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var questions = from qs in xdoc.Descendants("QuestionSet")
                let options = qs.Element("Options").Elements()
                select new {
                  Question = (string)qs.Element("Question"),
                  Options = options.ToDictionary(o => (int)o.Attribute("number"),
                                                 o => (string)o)
                };
```

That will return collection of anonymous objects for each question in set. All options will be in a dictionary with number as key:

```
foreach (var question in questions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(question.Question);

    foreach (var option in question.Options)        
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", option.Key, option.Value); 

    // or ConsoleWriteLine(question.Options[2])       
}
```

---

If you just want options from this particular xml:

```
var options = xdoc.Descendants("Option")
                  .ToDictionary(o => (int)o.Attribute("number"), o => (string)o);

Console.WriteLine(options[1]); // 10, 15
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = new XmlDocument();
d.LoadXml("yuor document text");

d.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().SelectMany(root => root.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().Where(x => x.Name == "Options").SelectMany(options => options.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().Select (option => option.Attributes["number"].Value))).Dump();
```

It could be a little bit agly. Maybe better to use foreach's or use XPATH  //options/option["number"] - (xpath query may be wrong)